# Using new Bing market place translator with Vb.net or C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, translation, bing

Has anyone had any luck/experience in using the new Bing Translator which is a paid service?

I can't find any useful code / examples for using the marketplace Bing Translator with C# or Vb.net.

I was using the Bing API v2 but Microsoft have limited the number of transactions.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Translator API is now offered via Azure Marketplace](http://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/microsofttranslator). There is limited free access available.

Examples / code can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/translation/p/gettingstarted1.aspx).